# Integrating the Google Drive Java SDK with Android with full access?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm starting to look at integrating the Google Drive SDK into Android. I need full access for my users, which it appears the Android SDK doesn't support, so I started following the instructions at this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client

> In some cases, applications may need to use the Google Drive web
>   service to access additional features or access broader scopes than
>   what is available in the Google Drive Android API. In these cases,
>   your application must use the Google APIs Client Library for Java.

So I started integrating the code sample below:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

I also followed these instructions:

> To install the Google API Java Client, you must download two ZIP
>   files, extract them, and then copy the JARs into your Java classpath.
>
> Download the Google Drive Java client library, which is bundled as a
>   ZIP file with all the required dependencies. Extract the ZIP file Add
>   all of the JARs within the libs directory to your classpath. Add the
>   google-api-services-drive-v2-[version].jar jar to your class path.

There's some problems though: I can only see one zip file per version in the downloads area, and it doesn't include the "google-api-services-drive-v2-[version].jar".

I'm not able to compile the code, and get errors like "DriveScopes cannot be resolved to a variable". I added the Google Play Services jar but that didn't help, either. I looked at related answers to this question, but they appear to apply to earlier versions of the SDK, and I don't feel comfortable about downloading an old beta jar from a Maven Repo.

What is the recommended way -today- to integrate Google Drive into an Android application, but with full access? This seems more complicated than it needs to be and I hope I'm just missing something really obvious.

Comment: I found the JAR and some more example code, will need to do some more digging to get it working and I'll come back and post the answer here if nobody else does before then. It's definitely not as easy or straightforward as the Dropbox API. ;)

Comment: Do you mind sharing where you get the good examples? or sharing the code somewhere? I have same problem and struggling here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476953/google-drive-client-api-android-not-working

Comment: I have created project in Android Studio by the way!

Comment: I put it on hold for now as Dropbox was far easier to integrate and we're going to wait until Google Drive is needed before we go down that path.

Comment: May be this can help you 

http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2014/03/android-preparing-to-access-google-drive-with-an-app-part-1/

Comment: and this ... http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Google-APIs