# Google Drive Client API + Android not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a android app as a beginner and no luck so far!! I am trying to get the list of image files from the user Drive account. With my exploration came to know that Google Drive for Android API does not give the full access scope. So I have to use the Google API for Java Client. I tried downloading the [sample example from here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/?repo=samples#samples%2Ftasks%2Fandroid). This tasks app is working perfectly on my mobile. So now i have changed this app to work with Google Drive. But its always throwing an exception in [this file](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/AsyncLoadTasks.java?repo=samples). Line#38 in my code reads as `client.files().list().execute().getItems();` //client is define as Drive variable in other file and am trying to get the list of files from the user account.

Exception is:

```
08-24 15:00:33.712  15422-15473/gattasrikanth.googledrive.example E/DriveSample﹕ Error
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:286)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
        at gattasrikanth.googledrive.example.AsyncLoadTasks.doInBackground(AsyncLoadTasks.java:40)
        at gattasrikanth.googledrive.example.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:57)
        at gattasrikanth.googledrive.example.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:35)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
            at gattasrikanth.googledrive.example.AsyncLoadTasks.doInBackground(AsyncLoadTasks.java:40)
            at gattasrikanth.googledrive.example.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:57)
            at gattasrikanth.googledrive.example.CommonAsyncTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyncTask.java:35)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any ideas where am doing wrong.
I have setup the project,package,SHA1 correctly on Google Console.
Not sure why it is working with TasksAPI but not with Drive API.

Comment: Why do you need full drive scope?

Comment: To read all the list images/files available in any given/root folder.

Comment: Please try this - May be this can help you 

http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2014/03/android-preparing-to-access-google-drive-with-an-app-part-1/

Comment: and this - http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Google-APIs

Comment: Yep!! Thats what I exactly needed and helpful! although i solved it few days back. Thanks for sharing those links!